# I save deep learning model as *.keras extension . tensorflow load_model give Layer error .How to solved it ? I can not re-run the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, load

code that I write

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/bciv2/SAVE_MODEL/beta_Necker cube.keras')
```

error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    252                 f"with the native Keras format: {list(kwargs.keys())}"
    253             )
--> 254         return saving_lib.load_model(
    255             filepath,
    256             custom_objects=custom_objects,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    279 
    280     except Exception as e:
--> 281         raise e
    282     else:
    283         return model

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    267                 asset_store = None
    268 
--> 269             _load_state(
    270                 model,
    271                 weights_store=weights_store,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py in _load_state(trackable, weights_store, assets_store, inner_path, skip_mismatch, visited_trackables)
    464             )
    465         elif isinstance(child_obj, (list, dict, tuple, set)):
--> 466             _load_container_state(
    467                 child_obj,
    468                 weights_store,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py in _load_container_state(container, weights_store, assets_store, inner_path, skip_mismatch, visited_trackables)
    532             else:
    533                 used_names[name] = 0
--> 534             _load_state(
    535                 trackable,
    536                 weights_store,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py in _load_state(trackable, weights_store, assets_store, inner_path, skip_mismatch, visited_trackables)
    433                 )
    434         else:
--> 435             trackable.load_own_variables(weights_store.get(inner_path))
    436 
    437     if hasattr(trackable, "load_assets") and assets_store:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py in load_own_variables(self, store)
   3529         all_vars = self._trainable_weights + self._non_trainable_weights
   3530         if len(store.keys()) != len(all_vars):
-> 3531             raise ValueError(
   3532                 f"Layer '{self.name}' expected {len(all_vars)} variables, "
   3533                 "but received "

ValueError: Layer 'dense_1' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0']
```

I use `model.save()`  to save deep learning model. In beginning I try to save with h5 extension and its give error to new tensorflow and they suggest to save as keras extension. Now this give error. I can not go back and run this code again because of server limitation capacity.

I want to load that model so that I can run or produced SHAP figure.

Comment: What is your TF version? I think the new syntax is `tf.keras.saving.load_model` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/load_model). I'm not sure when this changed.